# Iterating through a list of links and scraping with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

When I try to iterate a through a list of links and visit them with Selenium with this code:

```
# create link list
urlList = []
with open('my.txt','r') as f: 
for i in f:
    urlList.append(i)


# navigate to URL 
for i in (urlList):
    getUrl = driver.get(i)
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
```

I receive this error:

> > > selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32603,"message":"Cannot navigate to invalid URL"}
> > >       (Session info: chrome=51.0.2704.106)
> > >       (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248304,platform=Linux 4.2.0-16-generic x86_64

Apparently the for loop is generating newline characters from the list and feeding them into the driver.get method. How do I get it to feed urls instead?

Comment: Can you show then content of the `my.txt`?

Answer (score 2):

If your urls read from the file are getting newlines mixed in, try:

```
with open('my.txt','r') as f: 
    for i in f:
        urlList.append(i.strip())
```

This will remove leading and trailing whitespace from each `i`. Also, the `\n`s are not being generated by the loop, they exist in your file which probably has a url on each line, and a `'\n'` at the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

I run your program on my computer, But I don not get any error?

This is `my.txt` file, there are two china website url in it:

```
https://www.baidu.com/
https://www.sogou.com/
```

This is `test.py` file, It will `get` the websites in `my.txt`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
urlList = []
with open('my.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i in f:
        urlList.append(i)


for i in (urlList):
    print(i)
    getUrl = driver.get(i)
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
```

These are the output of my program:

```
➜ /tmp/selenium $ python3 test.py
https://www.baidu.com/

https://www.sogou.com/
```

So I think there may be other mistakes in your program. Can you show the content of the `my.txt` and the complete code?